# Privacy of ggplotly plots saving to plotly account

Tags: r, ggplot2, privacy, plotly

I am pretty new at using `plotly`, however when I have used it previously, any plots I created were sent to my `plotly` account.

Now, they appear in my RStudio viewer pane, but are not showing in 'My Charts' on `plotly`. This is ok, so long as anything I create in this manner is not being shown publicly without my knowledge.

Some code as an example:

```
    library(plotly)
    library(scales)

    py <- plotly(username="my_username", key="my_key")
    Sys.setenv("plotly_username" = "my_username")
    Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key" = "my_key")

    dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), length.out = 1000, by="15 min")
    data=rnorm(1000,1,2)
    colour=c(rep("Blue",500),rep("Pink",300),rep("Blue",200))

    DF=data.frame(dates,data,colour)

    g4 <- ggplot(DF, aes(dates, data,colour=colour,group=1))+geom_line()+geom_point()+
      scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%d-%m-%y"))+
      ggtitle("Test Plotly")+theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"))+xlab("")

    ggplotly(g4)
```

It may be worth mentioning that when I use the `py` and `Sys.setenv` above, using the command `plotly:::verify("my_username")` shows an error message saying it could not find my username, yet my api key is found.

Comment: [plotly R](https://plot.ly/r/) was updated recently using the [htmlwidgets.org](http://www.htmlwidgets.org) framework and now runs entirely locally. Consequently, you don't need a plotly account to use the R package.